# how can I select items from an SQL table with user set date parameters

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

so I have an SQL table which includes a column for dates. However id like to add a feature to my program where the user can input 2 different dates (a start date and end date) and all the items in the table that fall between those dates will be printed. Is this possible here is what some of my code looks like however I'm not sure if it will be useful

```
choice1 = input('would you like to view outflows from a specific time period? Or type "EXIT" to quit back to the main menu: ')

if choice1 == 'yes':
    datechoice1 = input('date from (formtat YYYY-MM-DD): ')
    datechoice2 = input('date to (formtat YYYY-MM-DD): ')
```

after this part I'm not too sure where to go from here in order to achieve this the variable which the date is stored in the 'outflow' table is just called 'date' btw

any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect to the database and execute the query something like

```
cursor.execute("""
   Select * from database.table
   Where datecolumn between %s and %s
   """, 
   (datechoice1, datechoice2)
 )
```

Comment: If the OP is using sqlite (and the question is tagged) then the placeholder will be `?`